# PHP function 1 call into function 2

Tags: php, function

I'm a php novice (be gentle) I have two functions, I want to be able to call `getUserLevel()` inside `adminOnlyAccess()` is this even possible to do? Both are functions are in `functions.php`.

This is `getUserLevel()`:

```
function getUserLevel(){    
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM author WHERE id = :sessionID';
    $stmt = dbConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sessionID', $_SESSION['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetch();

    return $data['role'];
}
```

This is `adminOnlyAccess()`:

```
function adminOnlyAccess($access = TRUE){   
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM author WHERE id = :sessionID';
    $stmt = dbConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sessionID', $_SESSION['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetch();

    if ($access == TRUE && $data['role'] != 1)
    {
        include '../accessdenied.php';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, did you give it a shot first? These both functions are probably defined without any namespace so they will be available globally in your code (you can call them wherever) as long as you include the `functions.php` file.

Comment: Here's a good source on the basics of functions: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP should have just tried it first

Comment: Is it possible? Short answer: Yes!

Comment: tip: if your only using column `role` you don't need to return all column from the query `*`, use `SELECT role FROM ..` instead.

Comment: Dave, please sorry, but I cannot see this disaster question. So I'll ask a serious question: `What is Your IQ level?`  - because You're wasting big amount of time to write a question, to chat with people when You could just test it (would take not more that 1-2 minutes)

Comment: I did try before I posted here. I used ‘$this->getUserLevel();‘. Guess I should have posted my test first, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... its perfectly possible

```
function adminOnlyAccess($access = TRUE){   

    $roles = getUserLevel();
    // $roles now has all the values returned by getUserLevel()

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM author WHERE id = :sessionID';
    $stmt = dbConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':sessionID', $_SESSION['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetch();

    if ($access == TRUE && $data['role'] != 1)
    {
        include '../accessdenied.php';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you can't. You can transform the `adminOnlyAccess` to look as follows:

```
function adminOnlyAccess($access = TRUE){   
    if ($access == TRUE && getUserLevel() != 1)
    {
        include '../accessdenied.php';
        exit();
    }
}
```